# How to display selectable attributes in product listing?

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, configurable-product, product-list

I want to display a size attribute in product listing as shown in the image

[image]

I created an attribute and configurable product. In the product detail page i am able to select attributes. I set 'Used in Product Listing to yes' for the attribute. I am not able to show it in the frontend listing. Is there any way to show attribute like this?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a trivial task. There is a good [tutorial](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/display-multiple-configurable-products-with-options-on-one-page-in-magento/) by Inchoo how to achieve it.

Pasting just a link as an answer is not a good practice but the solution is too complex with lot's of code chunks to be posted.

I can add that I tried this solution by myself and it works flawlessly.

Comment: This inchoo guys once trolled by publishing leo tolstoy's book as magento documentation. that is just wicked.

Comment: I can confirm also that the solution provided by Inchoo is a good one. The only think that you should have in mind is the performance.  If you have a lot of configurable products, with a lot of simple products associated to them can lead to a lot of queries and make your page slow.